# CSS3 transitions want to add a colour and fade it away

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to make a DIV background (which doesn't have a background color) flash red then ease out to blank again. now I  have used JS to add a new CLASS (which adds the red) to the DIV in question and CSS3 to add an easing to the background color. but it eases it IN, what I want is it to go RED then ease out. I guess I could do this by using JS to add multiple CLasss after a delay. but can CSS3 be used to do this entirely?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

If you want something like a highlighting you may want to use CSS3 animations. They are not supported in older browsers. Check [caniuse](https://caniuse.com/css-animation) for this.

The highlight is called on clicking the link. Here is the CSS (without vendor-prefixes):

```css
@keyframes highlight {
    0% {
        background: red
    }
    100% {
        background: none;
    }
}

#highlight:target {
    animation: highlight 1s;
}
```

```html
<div id="highlight"><a href="#highlight">Highlight</a></div>
```

Comment: thanks for the example but I'm looking to do this effect without the user click. On page load I am looking for specific DOM entries then adding a class. When that class is added i want it to flash red and fade back to nothing?

Comment: Awesome! I nailed it. thanks for the pointer to animations, that was the key. the only step I was failing on from your example was the MOZ specifics (not sure how your example page worked). sorted now thanks.

Comment: @drublic Is it possible to make the animation repeat on each successive click?

Comment: @TomSöderlund I think you could do it with `:focus`.

Comment: Example link down. Please create an inline live example

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it is to use the jQuery UI animate method, which extends the "normal" jQuery animate() to affect things like background-color.

Transitions like this is possible in css3 to, but obviously with not as wide browser support.

```
#maDiv {
   -webkit-transition:background-color 0.5s linear;
   -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
   -o-transition: background-color 0.5s linear;
   height: 20px;
   width: 20px;
   background:#000;
}

#maDiv:hover {
    background: #ff0;
}
```

That will fade the color when the user hovers the Div, and fade it back when mouse is out, over 0.5 seconds. For browser support details, see "css3 transition" here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/presentation